# String index out bound exception

Tags: java, hashmap, challenge-response

Hi everyone I'm trying to write a program to convert from roman numerals to Arabic numerals. However, I keep having issues with StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: -1. below is my code

```
package com.company;

import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        System.out.println(romanToArabic("CIV"));
    }
    public static int romanToArabic(String romanNumeral){
        Map <Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
        map.put('I', 1);
        map.put('V', 5);
        map.put('X', 10);
        map.put('L', 50);
        map.put('C', 100);
        map.put('D', 500);
        map.put('M', 1000);

        int result = 0;
        for (int i=0; i < romanNumeral.length(); i++){
            int current = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i));
            int next = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i-1));
            if (i>0 && current > next){
                result += current - 2*next;
            }

            result += current;
        }
        return result;
    }
```

Comment: `for (int i=0;` then `charAt(i-1)` and you're surprised that it fails with "index -1 is out of range"?? What did you expect that to do?

Comment: But notice the if condition in the loop. It's not supposed to fail. check out this post and tell me. I did pretty much the same thing. But mind seems not to work. https://www.google.com/amp/s/www.geeksforgeeks.org/convert-a-roman-number-to-decimal-using-hashmap-in-java/amp/

Comment: What `if` condition? The `charAt(i-1)` call is not inside an `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is in your first "for loop" iteration when "i=0"

In the following line you properly get a character "C" which has an index "0"

```
int current = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i));
```

Then on the next line "i" becomes -1 when code executes the statement (i-1)

```
int next = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i-1));
```

and thus you try to get a character with index "-1"

```
int next = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(-1));
```

and it follows you to the ***String index out bound exception***

Because string characters indexing starts with zero

Answer (score 0):

```
int next = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i-1));
```

"i-1" is -1 when you walk through the loop for the first time (i=0)

Answer (score 0):

As both mentioned you are starting at i = 0, then trying an  operation of (i-1),

Fix this by starting your loop at i = 1, or only doing this line (and the rest of the code):

```
int next = map.get(romanNumeral.charAt(i-1));
```

if i is greater than or equal to 1.